# Selenium hides web element behind navigation bar

Tags: firefox, java, selenium

I have a problem with writing a value into an input element.

[image: screenshot]

When Selenium appeals to this input field, the page scrolls to the top and the input hides behind the navigation bar.

Before appealing, I execute this code:

```
int elementPosition = element.getLocation().getY();
String js = String.format("window.scroll(0, %s)", elementPosition-90);
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(js);
```

But even after my scroll, the input is still hidden.

Also, I tried to set a value to this field through JavaScript:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '"+date+"')",element);
```

Unfortunately, this does not help either.

Environment: Selenium 3.6.0 ver, FireFox 66 ver.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following pair of methods to scroll into view:

```
/**
 * Wait until JQuery is inactive
 * @author Bill Hileman
 */
public void waitForJQueryToBeInactive() {

    Boolean isJqueryUsed = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
            .executeScript("return (typeof(jQuery) != 'undefined')");

    if (isJqueryUsed) {
        while (true) {
            // JavaScript test to verify jQuery is active or not
            Boolean ajaxIsComplete = (Boolean) (((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
                    .executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0"));
            if (ajaxIsComplete)
                break;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

}

/** 
 * Scroll a web element into view
 * @author Bill Hileman
 * @param ele - WebElement
 */
public void scrollIntoView(WebElement ele) {

    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(" + ele.getLocation().x + 
                                                                "," + ele.getLocation().y + ")");
    waitForJQueryToBeInactive();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The website I test for is written in an ExtJS single page type of web page.  When elements are not in view, I am still able to use the `.SendKeys()` method to type into the box.  It happens real quick, but the box I'm working with comes into focus on the screen, without any issue.

If you put a `thread.sleep();` right after the `.SendKeys()` statement, you should see the box you are interacting with in a visible location on the page.